# What does this line of Python code do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, syntax

I'm currently reading through a Python code repo and I'm not sure I understand this syntax:

```
Sp = S[:Kp,:]
Sc = S[Kp:,:]
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with splicing but I'm not sure of how the comma operator is being used. `S` comes from an external system and its format is not discernable by looking at the code. I'm going to guess it's a list/array/matrix. `Kp` is an integer variable.

What exactly will `Sp` and `Sc` hold after the above code is run?

Comment: `S` is a numpy array, most likely.

Comment: Looks like numpy and [numpy slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Comment: Actually `S` is read and populated from a matlab file is what I'm told. Any way to check if it's a numpy array?

Comment: `print(type(S))` will tell you the type. You're looking for something along the lines of `numpy.ndarray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S` is likely a numpy ndarray.  `Kp` is likely an integer.
 You guessed right that it was "splicing", but most people call this slicing.  It is slicing on rows, and the second `:` after the comma refers to all columns.

```
Sp = S[:Kp,:]
```

`Sp` is a subarray of `S` with all rows up to (but not including) `Kp`.

```
Sc = S[Kp:,:]
```

`Sc` is a subarray of `S` with all rows from `Kp` to the end (inclusive).

Comment: That I was able to guess. But what I'm unable to figure out is the use of the 'comma' and the succeeding `:`. Are they really doing anything? If I ignore them, I can discern what you said. But does having it change anything?

Comment: Having it doesn't change anything.  The code could equivalently have been `S[:Kp]` and `S[Kp:]`.

Comment: Sigh! I wish people wrote code with pieces that actually did something :P

Comment: `S[:Kp,:]` requires that `S` has at least two dimensions, so it is not quite the same as `S[:Kp]`.

Comment: That's true, but given that it does have at least two dimensions it should be same here.  OTOH, had it not been there I could not have been so quick to guess that we are dealing with a numpy array, so it did serve a purpose in that sense... ;)